# C++ std::inner_product works but shouldn't

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, inner-product

I use `std::inner_product` to count length of common prefix in 2 `strings`:

```
string a = "abcdef", b = "abc";
size_t r = std::inner_product(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), size_t(0),
                              [] (size_t v1, size_t v2) { return v1 + v2; }, 
                              [] (char c1, char c2) { return size_t(c1 == c2); });
```

I'd expect that it will work if size of `a` is less then size of `b`.
Why does it work if size of `a` is more then size of `b`?
Here is a standard implementation (`first2` will be invalid while `first1` will still be OK):

```
    template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class T>
    constexpr // since C++20
    T inner_product(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                                    InputIt2 first2, T init)
    {
            while (first1 != last1) {
                     init = std::move(init) + *first1 * *first2; // std::move since C++20
                     ++first1;
                     ++first2;
            }
            return init;
    }
```

Is it a case of unspecified behaviour?
[std::inner_product](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product)

Comment: Yes, it's plain old undefined behavior. The code reads past the end of the second range. It's a bug in the user's code.

Comment: Some algorithms got double iterator pair versions to protect against this. I think <numeric> got left out.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour, meaning that the standard says nothing about what is required to happen.    One of the joys (if you have masochistic tendencies) of undefined behaviour is that the behaviour you get may look like "it works".    The implementation of `std::inner_product()` with your implementation (i.e. your standard library) may be deliberately protecting you in this case - even though the standard doesn't require it to.   Or maybe you are getting "lucky".